# Production of ozone from oxygen and Le Chatelier's principle

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, kinetics

My NCERT textbooks says as follows:

> Since the formation of ozone from oxygen is an endothermic process, it is necessary to use a silent electrical discharge in its preparation to prevent its decomposition.

Reaction is:

$3\ce{O2}\ce{->}2\ce{O3}$ $\triangle H$=+142 kJ mol $^{-1}$

And somewhere on the net, I have learnt that silent **sparkless** discharge is needed as sparks may increase the temperature of the vessel/setup environment.

My question is, isn't the text contradicting the very principle of le Chatelier for endothermic processes, i.e the temperature should be as high as reasonably viable and allowable (for kinetics reason)?

Comment: Explain the downvote please.

Comment: I didn't down vote, just want to know the context of your question. Could it be that in the context of what you read "somewhere on the net", ozone formation is not the only process occurring so the higher temps were adversely affecting some other factor?

Comment: @J.Ari I just gave what I have learnt on the web, from some Q and A site which just cannot explain more for my question.

Comment: Seems you're not getting that you explicitly don't want to get to equilibrium here. That's why discharge is used.